# In left sidebar menu only one module should open at a time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, css

In my html page I want only one module to open at a time after clicking on main parent link. 
Right now after clicking on new module previous module dosen't close. For example in my page while clicking on "Inventory" module "Receiving" module should be closed.
I have given below google drive LINK for my Html page and supporting code. I tried to upload here in sample code but it didn't allowed me to upload some important supporting files for it like custom font files.

[enter link description here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B-PCfuTrE71OaS1VTDFPTno5MnM)

Comment: I don't see on Your page elements with neither `id="accordion"` and id="accordion1" which u reffer to in jQuery and `data-parent` attribute.

Comment: @ Kamil Kamiński Please check again just updated in html. Still not changed anything. Thanks for pointing though.

Comment: Post (not upload) the HTML/CSS that is specifically not working.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add `panel` class in both `<li class="parent_menu">`. This class is required by accordion module in bootstrap.

Comment: You are awesome. Thanks a ton for the help now it's working perfect.

Comment: Glad to help. I had the same issue with my app some time ago aswell :]